# Flutter dio not working for post request in flutter web

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I am trying to make an http post request using the Dio package on flutter Web with the code below but whenever click the button to make the request I get the error in the picture with no data returned.I dont get what may be causing the problem.

```
Map<String,dynamic> postData = {
  "email":"someemail@gmail.com",
  "password":"qwerty123456",
};

var resp = await dio.post("http://10.15.5.46/codeishweb/LoginUser.php",data: postData );
   if (resp.statusCode == 200) { 
      if(resp.data != null){
        print("not null");
       responseBody = resp.data;
       print("results ::$responseBody");
      }else{
        print("The request gave null");
      }
```

[image: Dio Error]

Comment: Hi, if you can add the error log here, it would be great. Also, I couldn't help but noticing that the `baseUrl` is an empty String. Issue must be somewhat related to that

Comment: I'm facing the same error. Same code working in android but in web req.body.name receive undefined value.

Comment: @AbdullahKhan did you find a solution for your issue? I have the sam problem. Works on Android but not web

Comment: @DrkStr I didn't remember clearly but i think i did this using http plugin. https://pub.dev/packages/http

Comment: I am facing the same issue, have you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think because of 'http', your URL should be 'https'